# Trying to triangulate from two (or three) known points.

Tags: geometry, triangles

If I'm at an unknown location, but I have visible points (monuments) that I know the location of, and I can measure the angle between them, I should be able to determine my location.  I'm thinking that with only two monuments, I can narrow my location down to 4 possible points but it seems that once add a third, I should be able to pinpoints my location.
I can get a very accurate read on the relative angles between them and know the coordinates of the monuments exactly.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Assuming you only know the locations of the two monuments (and not your distance to them) and the angle formed, you have an infinite number of possible locations. For example, if the angle between the monuments is exactly $90^{\circ}$, then you are somewhere on the circle formed with the monuments as endpoints on the diameter.

Answer (score 1):

The locus of points for which the angle between the monuments is fixed is a circle. If you have three monuments, you have three pairs, and thus three circles, which all intersect at your location.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically correct, although I think if you have two monuments then you have narrowed it down to two locations (one on either side of the two monuments).  Knowing a third helps as long as these points are not colinear.

Comment: How does that work? Looks like you're assuming that he knows **distance** to the monuments, which he doesn't.